# Content is not loaded?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, background-image

I have MVC 3 application. 
In one of div's I set background-image.

```
#wrapper {
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
background: url(../../Content/images/img01.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
```

In _Layout.cshtml I write this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Some Items -->
</div>
```

But image is not showed. If I write this:

```
<img src="../../Content/images/img01.jpg"/>
```

Html-page show this image correct.

Why this image is not setted on backgroun of div?

Comment: Is the CSS you posted above in the page or in a separate stylesheet at a different location?

Comment: @NathanTaylor at different location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrapper is a class.

You have defined the CSS as # which is an ID

EDIT:

Just so it makes sense your code must be:

```
#wrapper {
   width: 960px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   background: url(../../Content/images/img01.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed that the path to the image is valid from the context of your CSS file? If you CSS file is not in the same directory as your view, the image path may not be valid from the location of the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
background: url(../../Content/images/img01.jpg) no-repeat center top;
```

with

```
 background-image:url('/Content/images/img01.jpg') no-repeat center top;
```